# How to get some of 2 fields from a table

Tags: mysql, database, sum

I am having 2 tables.

### Table 1:-

```
id     name

1       k
2       a
```

### Table 2:-

```
id    sub1    sub2

1      10      20
2      30      40
```

I want the output as k -> 30 and a -> 70.

I fired the following query....

```
SELECT tbl_1.`name` , SUM(tbl_2.sub1 + tbl_2.sub2) as total 
from tbl_1, tbl_2 WHERE tbl_1.id = tbl_2.id;
```

**OUTPUT :-**

k -> 100

but i want like

k->30
a->70

if anyone has any idea please kindly help....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `SUM()`, and just use `tbl_2.sub1 + tbl_2.sub2`.

`SUM()` sums 'vertically', by summing the values of all the rows.

`+` sums 'horizontally' in this case, by summing the values of the columns.

The way you were doing it summed both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.name, (t2.sub1+t2.sub2) AS total
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select name, (sub1+sub2) as total from tbl_1, tbl_2 where tbl_1.id = tbl_2.id;
```

`SUM` is a column level operator and we need are trying to perform a row level operation.
A simple `+` should ideally solve the problem.